# What is the best method to build Ubuntu Linux from scratch?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, virtualization, source-code

I want to try out "*Linux From Scratch*" (LFS) using Ubuntu.

Since I know this could mess up my current Linux system, I want to know what is the best way to proceed.

What I've read so far is that I need a dedicated partition which is quite difficult to do with my current system.

Is installing another Ubuntu in a VirtualBox virtual machine and doing the work there the best way to go? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: I am not sure what *Linux From Scratch* refers to. When I [**Google *Linux From Scratch***](http://www.google.com/search?q=Linux+From+Scratch) there are many possibilties. Could you be more specific? Have you used VirtualBox (or VMware Player, et cetera) before? Does your computer's [CPU support virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vt-x#Processor)?  How much memory (RAM) do you have?

Comment: If you are interested in LFS, you might also want to have a look at Yocto https://www.yoctoproject.org/ . It can be built in a Virtualbox, but make sure you allocate as much RAM as you can or it will take ages to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to be careful of doing anything damaging to my computer so I got a new hard drive and used a bootable USB drive as my host system and built LFS on the blank hard drive as this would be the safest option.

However, the LFS team goes pretty far to ensure neither the host nor the build can damage the other.  Chapter 4 sets the stage to ensure this, just follow the directions carefully and you'll be safe.  When you get to Chapter 5, you do very little in the host system everything is done as user lfs which should protect your current system.

Source: I just did an LFS build myself!

Comment: A lot of the software that's listed as required for the host system isn't able to be installed. How does one get around this?